# AND isHidden = 0 is not taking into consideration when running this sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have this sql server query - that works almost - but for some reason it also returns results where ishidden is not 0 even though I have stated in the query that it should only return results where ishidden = 0. Can someone help me fix this ? Here is the sql query:

```
SELECT p.productId, p.colorId, p.creationDate, p.productName, 

p.description, p.oldprice, p.price, p.isPriority, p.isHidden, p.isOffer, p.isInStock, 
p.sortorder, p.colorId, pc.catid, c.picurl, c.isfrontpic, c.picid, pc.catname FROM ProductAndCat pac  INNER JOIN Product 
as p on pac.productid = p.productid INNER JOIN ProductCat as pc on pac.catid = pc.catid LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT productid, picurl,isfrontpic, picid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY isfrontpic DESC) rn 
FROM productpic) c ON c.rn = 1 AND p.ishidden = 0 AND p.productId = c.productId order by productid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added the `p.ishidden = 0` to the join condition for the left join of the derived table `c`. Try moving it to a proper `WHERE p.ishidden = 0` after to joins.

The end of the query should look something like this:

```
     FROM productpic )c
       ON c.rn = 1
      AND p.productId = c.productId
  WHERE p.ishidden = 0
  ORDER BY productid;
```

Comment: After the left join, just before the order by.

Comment: One question - wouldn't it give the same result if I add it here: INNER JOIN ProductCat as pc on pac.catid = pc.catid AND p.ishidden = 0  LEFT JOIN

Comment: Yes, it should be equivalent. But as it is a condition limiting the set and not a specification for the join it should be in a where clause.